# Как растянуть дочерний StackPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WebDownloader.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WebDownloader"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Initialized="Window_Initialized" Closed="Window_Closed" ResizeMode="NoResize" Width="230" Height="190">
<Grid>
    <StatusBar Height="20" FontFamily="Times New Roman" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StatusBarItem Content="Item 1 of 5" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Width="99" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="10"/>
            <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

Ребят, помогите новичку. Два вопроса.

1. Как сделать StackPanel, что бы она автоматически растягивалась на ширину StatusBar (StatusBar автоматически растягивается на ширину формы)? Сейчас StackPanel растягивается на ширину контента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Почему если StackPanel задать ширину формы (т.е. 230), то StackPanel будет больше формы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучшим решением будет отказаться от `StackPanel`

Comment: А чем, посоветуйте?

Comment: обычный `Grid` - универсальное решение

Comment: с этим вопросом разобрались?

Comment: В прицепе да, только пришлось повозится со вставкой Grid. Через ItemsPanelTemplate получилось, а так не хотел. Спасибо.

Comment: А по второму вопросу я так и не разобрался...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64286/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-kirill-k).